# Page Layout and implementation

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

I have a single-page layout that uses # in a fixed navigation to move up and down the page.
When the page loads I want the viewport to display the second section not the top section.

Do I have to use something like an "onload" go to #first when the page is loaded in the browser?

Here is a website that accomplishes what I am trying to do: http://volll.com/#section_main

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#first">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second">Second</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>


<section id="top">
  <h2>Top</h2>
  <p> blah </p>
</section>

<section id="first">
  <h1>First</h1>
  <p>You see this first</p>
</section>

<section id="second">
   <h2>Two</h2>
   <p>blah</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Just use "http://example.com/#second".

Comment: FYI, the example page you provided does not load.

Comment: example.com/#second    -how does that work if the page is index.html? confused, sorry. thanks for the fast response btw.

Comment: Use index.html/#second.It will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="window.location='#second'">
```